# Open a separate page for each operation in html

Tags: php, html, web

I created the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>operationno</td>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>status</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1001</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>open</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1002</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>open</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is to let the user press the open link that is beside each operation and open another page to complete the operation. The page will be:

```
<form>
Operation No: <input type="text" name="opno"><br>
Description: <input type="text" name="desc">
</form>
```

One idea that I know but I don't know how to implement is to let the open link contains link and at the end of it has the operation number.

Comment: `<a href="whatever" target="_blank">...</a>` Does not warrant a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PHP you can open the new link with GET parameters something like

Javascript-------

```
var el = document.getElementById("elToClick");
el.addEventListener("click",function () {
    window.open("http://yoursite.com/script.php?operation=1001","_blank");
})
```

or you can do this with simple

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/script.php?operation=1001" target="_blank"></a>
```

then in PHP you can access it

```
$value = $_GET['operation'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like:

```
<td><a href="page.php?operation_number=1002" target="_blank">open</a></td>
```

And then access it on `page.php` with `$_GET['operation_number']`.